# Cannot make post request using devise token auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, vue.js, ruby-on-rails-5, axios

I cant seem to make a post request to my controller endpoint; however, I could create a user and `get` all users using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth).

By following their documentation, I can CRUD a user. If I create another endpoint, in the user controller with a `post` route, Im getting:

> Filter chain halted as :authenticate_user! rendered or redirected

But `get` works. My `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      :headers => :any,
      :expose  => ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
      :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :patch, :options]
  end
end
```

The user CRUD work only with [their](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) paths endpoints but not mine.

```
# controllers/api/v1/api_controller.rb
module Api::V1
  class ApiController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    respond_to :json
  end
end

# controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb
module Api::V1
  class UsersController < ApiController

    def create
      render json: 'created'
    end

  end
end

# routes
scope module: 'api' do
  namespace :v1 do
    post '/users/test', to: 'users#create'    # not authenticated!
    get '/users/test', to: 'users#create'     # authenticated.. works
    # resources :users, only: [:index, :show] # no issues here
  end
end
```

Postman can `post` when I added the header but not from browser. Not sure an issue with CORS but I think not. Ive tried a fresh rails 5 api and same.
My js function looks like:

```
axios.post(`${window.apiUrl}/v1/users/test`, { headers: headerData, project: { title: 'help' } })
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was how I post data with axios. I should have the data before the headers:

```
axios.post('url', <data-to-post>, <headers>)
```

Instead, I was only sending the `params` and not the `headers`. Problem solved.